# Lightning Web Component on Salesforce's Public Site

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, force.com-sites

I created a LWC Components and used in Visualforce Pages to make this page Public.

For this I created New domain  in my developer edition

SetUp--> Sites,  Created a new Domain name called `preschool` So the domain Name is

`preschool-developer-edition.ap16.force.com`

And Created a new Site label and  added My visual force page  in `Active Site Home Page`, saved and Activated.

Now if i go and preview the private site. It display as below.

[image]

The developer console shows an error:

```
lightning.out.delega…v=1584969017223:126 GET https://preschool-developer-edition.ap16.force.com/c/EnrollmentVf.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT 500 (Internal Server Error)
requestApp  @   lightning.out.delega…v=1584969017223:126
use @   lightning.out.delega…v=1584969017223:140
script.onload   @   lightning.out.js?v=2:46
load (async)        
loadDelegateScript  @   lightning.out.js?v=2:43
(anonymous) @   lightning.out.js?v=2:53
(anonymous) @   lightning.out.js?v=2:78
```

Comment: Possibly related answers that may help: [answer 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/160119/2984), [answer 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/170736/2984). Basically, there may be a compilation error, or there may be a permissions issue. Make sure that the Guest Site user has access to the enrollment object (and any related objects), and make sure your app is still valid (try making a trivial change and saving again). Also make sure all your aura:dependency tags are present for any dependencies.

Comment: @sfdcfox i have given all Read, Write permission for the enrollment 
 object still getting this error `https://preschool-developer-edition.ap16.force.com/c/EnrollmentVf.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, found it was all down to permissions

1. enabling LWC in the Site:  in the Salesforce UI - on Setup > Sites > (your site page) > tick 'Lightning Features for Guest User
2. making sure Lightning Application is set with:
   `<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL"  implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">`

Comment: Thankyou. `ltng:allowGuestAccess` worked for me